# Why future forEach is looping more than expected?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two functions, 
First one to get the users from Firestore. Then I use "Future.ForEach" to loop on those users.

```
 Future<List> getData() async {
    targetData.clear();

    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(currentUserId)
        .collection('chats')
        .getDocuments()
        .then((userChats) async {
          // Only two documents are coming from the db
      return await Future.forEach(userChats.documents, getTargetData)
          .then((onValue) {
        print('forEech is done');
      });
    });

    print('getData Returen');
    // I use "targetData" to build viewList
    return targetData;
  }
```

Calling this function from the Future.forEach

```
  Future<List> getTargetData(DocumentSnapshot targetDoc) async {
    print('looping');

    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(targetDoc.documentID)
        .get()
        .then((targetRef) {
      targetData.add(new TargetUserData(
          targetRef.documentID,
          targetRef.data['nickname'],
          targetRef.data['photoUrl'],
          targetDoc.data['timestamp'],
          targetRef.data['token'],
          targetDoc.data['unseen']));
    });

    return targetData;
  }
```

I'm calling getData from inside the FutureBuilder

```
return new FutureBuilder(
 future: getData(),
 builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
   case ConnectionState.none:
   case ConnectionState.waiting:
    return buildLoading();
   default:
    if (snapshot.hasError)
      return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
   else
      return createListView(context, snapshot);
   }
 },
);
```

When I run the app it works perfectly fine and as expected - Here is the log from the print statement:

- I/flutter (18780): looping
- I/flutter (18780): looping I/flutter
- (18780): forEech is done
- I/flutter (18780): getDataReturen

[Hot Restart - First Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piwCJ.png)

I expect on hot reload that I get the same result But, what is coming is!!

- I/flutter (18780): looping
- I/flutter (18780): looping
- I/flutter (18780): looping
- I/flutter (18780): forEech is done
- I/flutter (18780): getDataReturen
- I/flutter (18780): forEech is done
- I/flutter (18780): getDataReturen

[Hot Reloads ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH9CZ.png)

Question: Why the forEach is looping more than expected?

Comment: Looks like `getData()` is being called twice. How and where are you calling it?

Comment: @MouadDebbar - I'm calling it from the FutureBuilder. I modified the post and added the part of the code where I'm calling it.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with `Future.forEach` - looks to be some confusion further up the stack. Whatever code is calling `return new FutureBuilder(` is _also_ being called twice.

Comment: BTW - your async code will be easier to follow if you avoid mixing and matching between `async`/`await` and `Future.then`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by reframing the code:

```
  Future<List> _getData() async {
    var allUsers = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments();

    List<TargetUserData> users = [];
    for (var userData in allUsers.documents) {
      if (currentUserId != userData.documentID) {
        await getTargetData(userData.documentID).then((targetData) {
          TargetUserData targetUserData = TargetUserData(
              userData.documentID,
              userData.data['nickname'],
              userData.data['photoUrl'],
              targetData[0],
              userData.data['token'],
              targetData[1],
              targetData[2]);
          users.add(targetUserData);
        });
      }
    }
    return users;
  }





Future getTargetData(var targetId) async {
    List targetData = [];

    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(currentUserId)
        .collection('chats')
        .document(targetId)
        .get()
        .then((advData) {
      if (advData.data != null) {
        targetData.add(advData.data['timestamp']);
        targetData.add(advData.data['unseen']);
        targetData.add(advData.data['lastMsg']);
      } else {
        targetData.add('0');
        targetData.add('0');
        targetData.add('Start Chating!');
      }
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print('on error: $onError');
    });

    return targetData;
  }
```